# Q: What's the name of this type of keyboard filter interaction?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns, search, terminology

I want to know a name for the type of keyboard filtering where a each time a user enters a character, the rest of the keyboard disables all characters which aren't relevant anymore because no word can be formed which would match the current context.

As an example: the possible inputs are *all countries* of the world.

1. The user is presented with a normal keyboard with all letters from `A` to `Z`.
2. The user presses `H` and as a result, all letters of the keyboard are disabled except `A`, `O` and `U`. This is because the only matching countries that can be entered now are H`a`iti, H`u`ngary, H`o`nduras and H`o`ly See.

A real live example of this behaviour with public transportation station names can be found on the ticket machines here in Switzerland as seen here:
[image: ZVV Ticket machine]

What would be the name of such a keyboard or keyboard behaviour?

Comment: Wohoo, Schwiiz! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft calls it "Text Suggestions For Software/Hardware Keyboard" but I also heard the term "predictive keyboard". I would recommend the second due to less complexity of the term.

Here is the link to activate Text Suggestions For Hardware Keyboard on Windows 10:
https://winaero.com/blog/text-suggestions-hardware-windows-10/